# Node-Red difference between current value and previous value

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I’m trying to make a Node-Red flow that calculates the difference between current and previous values of tags(variables).
I succeeded to do that for one value (inject a numeric value at once), but I can’t figure out how to do it for multiple tags!
If someone could address me I would appreciate it!
Thank you,

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67598377/edit) the question to add a lot more details here. What tags are you talking about? Show what you have working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code sample:

```
 if(typeof prev_value == 'undefined')
    prev_value = 0;
msg.payload = prev_value;
prev_value++;
return msg;
```

An other way is to store a variable in *context*:

```
msg.payload = context.get("my_value");
if(msg.payload == undefined) msg.payload = 0;
context.set("my_value", msg.payload + 1);
return msg;
```